# Wasted spark ignition spark plug type

Tags: ignition

I have a couple of follow up questions on wasted spark ignition: I heard wasted spark igniton systems are hard on spark plugs. How does wasted spark compare to say COP ignition and do wasted spark ignition systems require special spark plugs that are different than standard spark plugs? Any help would be greatly apprciated.

Comment: Where did you hear that wasted spark is hard on spark plugs?

Comment: I can't remember where I heard it. Just want to know if they are because of the reverse firing pattern in the opposing cylinder. and does anyone know if Wasted Spark is any better than cop and are special plugs required for wasted spark. The reason I asking these questions is because I have heard alot of negative things on it so if wasted spark is so good why then don't you see it on the high performance camaros and mustangs instead of COP. I have wasted spark on my 2003 jeep grand cherokee 4.0 and I would like to change it over to COP if it possible hoping for a performance and mileage boost.

Comment: If you’re burning 100% of the fuel, your car is efficient.  The biggest issue with a 4.0 Jeep is the size of the engine.  Mine managed 15MPG (UK) at best.  Changing the ignition system will be expensive but won’t make your car run any more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Waste spark ignition fires two cylinders at a time, one naturally on compression stroke, the other paired cylinder on exhaust. one side is fired straight polarity ie fired from plug to ground electrode. other side is fired reverse polarity ie spark jumps from side electrode to the center electrode. Best replacement plugs are double platinum. I change spark plugs as per the owners manual and have not had any issues.
My truck is a 2007 Ford ranger 3 litre V6 vulcan engine.